# PHP not working after MacOS update to High Sierra

Tags: php, linux, macos, apache

I updated my mac to newest version of os. When I try to run PHP project, browser shows the php code instead of interpreting it. I noticed that in new OS php is in version 7.1. I installed 5.6 (it's required for me) using homebrew and change module in httpd.conf to:

> LoadModule php5_module
>   /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.31_7/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Here's apache error log:

> [Tue Sep 26 23:59:38.600410 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 980]
>   AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Tue Sep 26 23:59:38.622998
>   2017] [core:notice] [pid 980] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty
>   error detected in the parent process AH00557: httpd:
>   apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro-Kamil.local AH00558:
>   httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally
>   to suppress this message [Tue Sep 26 23:59:48.838005 2017]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 991] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)
>   PHP/5.6.31 configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Sep 26
>   23:59:48.838097 2017] [core:notice] [pid 991] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following lines to my httpd.conf file fixed the problem:

```
AddType x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5
```

Hopefully this helps!

Edit: just to provide a bit more detail, as crmpicco suggests, I did also replace the new High Sierra httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files with my old Sierra ones like so:

```
mv httpd-vhosts.conf~previous httpd-vhosts.conf
mv httpd.conf~previous httpd.conf
```

Even after all of this and restarting Apache it still wasn't working - had to do a reboot for everything to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

The MacOS upgrade process seems to move your Apache config out into `~previous` files, whilst creating new, fresh versions. You just need to move them back. This worked for me:

```
mv httpd-ssl.conf~previous httpd-ssl.conf
mv httpd-vhosts.conf~previous httpd-vhosts.conf
mv httpd.conf~previous httpd.conf
```

Check the syntax.

```
apachectl -S
```

Restart Apache.

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: I tried this, but without the lines in my answer, it still didn't work. Maybe you had those lines in your old config files? Also, I generally like to start with the fresh config files and add the stuff I need, in case new things were added.

Comment: This was pissing me off but this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP5.6 with HighSierra

1. Enable building of shared Apache Handler module
   Make sure you have the latest version of PHP56 installed along with http option enabled (either install/upgrade/reinstall as needed)

   $brew upgrade php56 --with-httpd
2. Linking the module in Apache2 Config file
   Add following statement in apache2 config file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

   LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.32_8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
3. Adding the PHP5 config file

   Make a copy from the php7.conf

   $ cd /etc/apache2/other ; sudo cp php7.conf php5.conf

   Replace php7_module with php5_module
4. Restart Apache Server

   $ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your issue is with PHP, but is with your machine's domain name. Notice the message, "*Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.*" **Check the domain settings in your httpd.conf file.** You should also check your /etc/hosts file for any conflicts there as well.

[This guide for installing and using Apache/MySQL/PHP via Homebrew has been immensely useful.](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions) It applies to macOS Sierra, but will work with High Sierra as well. It will also show you how to install multiple PHP versions and a convenient way to switch back-and-forth between them, if that interests you (or just keep a single PHP version running).

I like going the Homebrew route as opposed to Vagrant or MAMP because it's closer to a native installation and uses less resources. Hope that helps!

Comment: The ServerName message is just a warning. If everything else is configured properly, it shouldn't cause any issues (I ran my local env with this warning for a long time before finally fixing it up).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here using MAMP and php 5.6: just after have updated to High Sierra (which is probably a Sierra with too much weed..) Apache2 stopped working.

After hours I finally resolved with this command:

`cp /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.25/conf/php.ini.temp /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.25/conf/php.ini`

And reapplied my custom changes to the php.ini. (in my case memory_limit and short_open_tag)

Restarted MAMP and it worked at the first try.

Answer (score 0):

After you added

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.31_7/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

you have to add

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
# If php is turned on, we respect .php and .phps files.
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

# Since most users will want index.php to work we
# also automatically enable index.php
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

to your

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Don't forget

```
apachectl restart
```

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the homebrew option too, in the end i decided to use Vagrant. you can leave your project files where they are and use vagrant to locally serve. I used the laravel/homestead box follow the guide on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead and in Homestead.yaml - you can use the same box for laravel and wordpress etc. it is also much more future proof for the next osx upgrade and you can easily choose the php version on a site by site basis

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/www/mysite/
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite
      type: "nfs"
sites:
    - map: mysite.app
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite/dist
      php: "5.6"
```

and in /etc/hosts/ add

```
192.168.10.10 mysite.app
```

Answer (score -2):

You can download the Xampp version that support PHP 5.6.31 and run your app with Xampp.

If you don't want to do that I think that you need to go back to MacOs Sierra, remember that PHP 5.6 it's old, the new systems are coming with the latest version!

Comment: You say this as though downgrading PHP is not an option and neither is running PHP5 side-by-side with PHP7. Is this because you know that neither of these things is possible, or because it's outside the scope of your answer?

Comment: I say this because the new MacOs use PHP 7 in the core, so, downgrading PHP could be a disaster

Comment: As OP mentions, s/he's using Brew to handle PHP version(s) so this is not a problem at all.